# How get pid/name of process that launched this process

Tags: linux, process, fork, pid

Process A (pid 1, name "progA") launches process B (pid 2, name "progB").  Is there a way for process B to get the pid / name of the process that launched it?

I'm working in Qt5/C++ on Linux.

Comment: `getppid()` to get the parent process ID.

Comment: Does that always work?  If the shell forks a bash script, is the parent set?  (Or is it ALWAYS set)

Comment: Yes, it always works. It's just part of the way processes work on Unix.  Every process has a parent (except the initial process -- traditionally `init`, but `systemd` on modern Linux), and `getppid()` returns its PID.

Comment: Why would there be any difference for a script run by the shell?

Comment: `bash` scripts have a `$PPID` variable. How do you think it sets it?

Comment: I now that when a process forks it can remain as parent or completely detach from the fork.  If it completley detaches I wasn't sure if the original PID was remembered.  Sounds good for an answer however

Comment: @TSG There is no "detach from the fork". If parent process terminates then init process with PID 1 becomes parent (unless another subreaper process is set by `prctl()`).

Comment: @TSG If the parent process exits before the child, the value returned by `getppid()` in the child will change to the new parent that adopts it.